# Https Post Request Not Working in Android

Tags: android, post, authentication, https, header

Im trying to make a loginApplication  into a website , by sending a Https Post Request and geting the source code for the next page after login "in android"
i'v watch lot of videos but nothing work : 
Any Help Please in this code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        try {
            new DownloadSourceCodeTask().execute("Link");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in Main", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
        }

    }   private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urls) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;
        URL url = new URL(urls);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not An Http Connction");
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            String param="ssousername=" + URLEncoder.encode("usernamevalue","UTF-8")+
            "password="+URLEncoder.encode("passwordvalue","UTF-8");
            httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1256");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Networking", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return in;
    }


    private String DownloadSourceCode(String url){
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in=OpenHttpConnection(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Error in connection",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return "";
        }

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        int charRead;
        String str = "";
        char[]inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];

        try{
            while((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0){
                String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
                str+=readString;
                inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
            }
            in.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.d("Error in connection",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return "";
        }
        return str;
    }


    private class DownloadSourceCodeTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void , String>{

        ProgressDialog dialog;
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
            return DownloadSourceCode(urls[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", 
                    "Loading. Please wait...", true);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            if(dialog.isShowing()){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
            text.setText(result);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A resource, not a debugging service. "Please help with this code" is not a question. Please explain what the problem is. In which way does it not work? What results are you getting and how do they differ from the desired results? Include any error messages you receive, verbatim (don't just describe them).

Comment: i need to post username and password to login page in https website ok im search alot on the internet but icannt find the best solution for this , then i found this code but it's not working ,, about the error message it still give me application running to much work then curshing ,, any help please

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an '&' before the password parameter, adding 2 lines after connect() and changing the encoding to UTF-8 in the content-type. See the new code below:

```
try {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        String param="ssousername=" + URLEncoder.encode("usernamevalue","UTF-8")+
        "&password="+URLEncoder.encode("passwordvalue","UTF-8");
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1256");
        httpConn.connect();
        httpConn.getOutputStream().write(param.getBytes());
        httpConn.getOutputStream().flush();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Networking", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: still crushing , excuse me but did u know the correct way that i get the link that i send the post data for it and make the login coz maybe the wrong be from the link